# Mod Rewrite - set default path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have "sandbox space" on my server where I develop projects for my clients. Is possible to have some simple edit of htaccess so I can use rewritten urls during development proccess?

the dev address is in this format: https://client.mydomain.com/projectName/pageName/

And I need to use rewrite rules like those:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ page.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It should be rewritten to:
https://client.mydomain.com/projectName/page.php?url=pageName

But it is currently rewriten to: 
https://client.mydomain.com/page.php?url=projectName/pageName

Is there some solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You are rewriting to `?url=projectName` here, not `?url=pageName` - you have no “page name” that you could capture from the original URL.

Comment: So if you actually want `/projectName/page.php?url=projectName` - well then add `$1/` in front of your substitution …

Comment: @CBroe - My bad - I gave there bad url. I want to rewrite url: https://client.mydomain.com/projectName/pageName/

Comment: Then try something like `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ $1/page.php?url=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Your .htaccess file should have the path /projectName/.htaccess , not in / as /.htaccess ?